# Get Server URL of an Email Attachment using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm developing an app that deals with emails. What I need is to get the URL of the location the attachment is stored on the exchange server. I can't download the attachment to my local machine so the attachment has to be accessed on the exchange server.

Is this possible?

I have looked online but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EWS no there is no URL to download an Attachment directly you need to know the AttachmentId (generally you would get this by using the GetItem operation) then you can use the GetAttachment operation to get the contents of the attachment (which is a Base64 Stream). see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getattachment-operation